# VLOOKUP to consider case-sensitive Values

Tags: validation-rule

I'm having a validation rule to check whether the name is already created or not.

```
AND(VLOOKUP($ObjectType.ProductComp__c.Fields.Name, $ObjectType.ProductComp__c.Fields.Name, Name) = Name, OR(ISNEW(), ISCHANGED(Name))).
```

The problem here I'm facing is, since
VLOOKUP is case insensitive when a user creates

record1 : test

record2 : Test it is saving. But ideally it should restict it from saving.How should I overcome this.

I tried using LOWER($ObjectType.ProductComp__c.Fields.Name) but it's throwing error as "Expected , received Object". Any Ideas please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LOWER` function to convert all text in lowercase and then compare them. Normally when we compare text its better if we convert them in UPPERCASE or LOWERCASE

```
AND(VLOOKUP(LOWER($ObjectType.ProductComp__c.Fields.Name), LOWER($ObjectType.ProductComp__c.Fields.Name), LOWER(Name)) = LOWER(Name), OR(ISNEW(), ISCHANGED(Name)))
```

You might need to quick fix it as I didn't get chance to test it.

Comment: modified it to AND(LOWER(VLOOKUP(($ObjectType.ProductComp__c.Fields.Name), ($ObjectType.ProductComp__c.Fields.Name), (Name))) = LOWER(Name), OR(ISNEW(), ISCHANGED(Name)))